# Unflattening Layer in Keras

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, reshape, flatten

I would like to create a simple Keras neural network that accepts an input matrix of dimension `(rows, columns) = (n, m)`, flattens the matrix to a dimension `(n*m, 1)`, sends the flattened matrix through a number of arbitrary layers, and in the final layer, once more unflattens the matrix to a dimension of `(n, m)` before releasing this final matrix as an output.

The issue I'm having is that I haven't found any documentation for an Unflatten layer at the [keras.io](https://keras.io) page, and I'm wondering whether there is a reason that such a seemingly standard common use layer doesn't exist. Is there a much more natural and easy way to do what I'm proposing?

Comment: did you consider keras.layers.reshape?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`Reshape`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#reshape) layer for this purpose. It accepts the desired output shape as its argument and would reshape the input tensor to that shape. For example:

```
from keras.layers import Reshape

rsh_inp = Reshape((n*m, 1))(inp)  # if you don't want the last axis with dimension 1, you can also use Flatten layer

# rsh_inp goes through a number of arbitrary layers ...

# reshape back the output
out = Reshape((n,m))(out_rsh_inp)
```